# There is no data "networks": {}, in Smart contract .json

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, blockchain, smartcontracts, metamask

I am trying to connect meta mask from `nuxt.js` application

What I have done is like this

1.`yarn truffle init`

2.make `contract/SingleNumRegister.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
contract SingleNumRegister{
    struct StoreNumber{
        address from;
        uint256 number;
    }
    StoreNumber[] public storeNumbers;
    function set(uint256 num) public {
        storeNumbers.push(StoreNumber(msg.sender,num));

    }
    function get() public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 index = storeNumbers.length -1;
        return storeNumbers[index].number;
    }
}
```

3.`yarn truffle build` it makes `/build/contracts/SingleNumRegister.json`

4.make `migrations/2_deploy_contract.js`

```
const SingleNumRegister = artifacts.require('SingleNumRegister')
module.exports = function(deployer){
    deployer.deploy(SingleNumRegister)
}
```

5.change `truffle-cinfig.js` for my local `Ganache`

```
networks: {
 development: {
  host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
  port:7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
  network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
 },
```

6.`yarn truffle deploy` -> deployment success.

Then, I am trying to access with this script `plugins/web3.js`.

```
import Web3 from "web3"
import artifacts from "~~/build/contracts/SingleNumRegister.json"

export default async function(context,inject){

    let web3;
    
    if (typeof window != 'undefined' && typeof window.ethereum != 'undefined'){
        web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
        window.ethereum.enable().catch((error) =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    }else if (
        typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
        typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined'
    ){
        web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
    }else {
        const httpEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(httpEndpoint))
        inject('web3',web3)
    }
   
    let networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
    console.log("networkId:"+ networkId);
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
        artifacts.abi,
        artifacts.networks[networkId].address
    )
    inject('web3',web3)
    inject('contract',contract)
}
```

it shows error `client.js:227 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')`

in `SingleNumRegister.json` , there is no data for networks.

this file is made at process `2` and I did nothing for this.

```
  "networks": {},
  "schemaVersion": "3.4.4",
  "updatedAt": "2022-01-04T08:12:18.731Z",
  "devdoc": {
    "kind": "dev",
    "methods": {},
    "version": 1
  },
```

Is it correct? or Where should I fix???

Comment: I am facing this issue and it seems there's no answer to this problem on the internet.
:(

Answer (score 0):

After compiling your contract with  `truffle compile` run

```sh
truffle migrate
```

**and voila!**
You should have something like this,

```json
 "networks": {
    "1641312206935": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0xc447AFC10846f39540EF1e2CC6F35f91903d8f94",
      "transactionHash": "0x06803935f6bb461092b748953ab556cef2d9ceb610761c67193eb1cf6f07f970"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
truffle deploy --reset
```

try running this

Comment: How does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are looking at the `artifacts` which are located at a directory which are configured in `truffle-config.js` next to `contracts_build_directory`.

I made the same mistake. After checking proper `artifacts` please run `truffle migrate` of `truffle deploy --reset`.